# How to transfer aes key from js to java server?

Tags: javascript, java, aes, forge

I am trying to transfer AES key generate in js:

```
var AESkey = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);
```

exapmle if printed condsole i have "§½­üå8bdÈP"

but printed in my java server it is "Â—Â§Â‡Â˝Â­\u001eĂĽĂĄ8b\u000edĂ?\u0012PÂ›"
(other data are ok)

I tried to get the bytes with **Buffer.from(AESkey)** but instead of getting a 16 bytes buffer I get a 22/24/25.. buffer lenghts.

In which format can I transfer the key and how can I get my AESkey to that format  in js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

- make a base64 encoded string on client side
- send base64-encoded string to server
- decode base64 in Java to get the byte sequence back

This way the byte sequence can be safely transported.